# What is the best way to avoid users triggering the click event of a disabled button?

Tags: asp.net

When we disable an asp:button using `button.Enabled = false`, it just

- add the class `aspNetDisabled`,
- add `disabled='disabled'` to the control, and
- removes the `__doPostBack('button', '');` from the onclick function

But if an user manually type the code through the console, he can trigger the event.

What's the best way to be safe from it? should I encapsulate all my events with
`if (sender.Enabled) { do things }`? This seems to be easy to forget, is there a better way, or a safer way?

**EDIT**: I am not disabling `EventValidation`, as you can see here: [prnt.sc/en7oeh](http://prnt.sc/en7oeh)
what could be causing the request to be valid?
My button is inside an UserControl.

**EDIT 2**: I just tried using a plain page (without masterpages and usercontrols) with the disabled button and I still managed to call the button_Click method by typing `__doPostBack('button', '')` in the console. EventValidation seems to not work at all. I also checked my web.config file, there's nothing there disabling EventValidation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggestion by setting the button `button.Enabled = false` and then executing the code manually. Aspnet immediately threw the error `Invalid postback or callback argument`, as it's supposed to. That probably means you turned off `EventValidation`. That is **not** something you should do, it makes your site much more vulnerable to malicious intent.

That said you can still disable the code by checking the state of the button in the click method.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LinkButton1.Enabled == true)
    {
        //execute actual code only when the correct button is enabled
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not disabling EventValidation in any way, I am, however, loading the button from inside an UserControl